# ReactJS & ChartJS - getElementAtEvent is valid in console but not from code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

My Code:

```
<Bar className="bar-chart"
ref={(r) => (this.chart = r)}
data={data} options={chartOptions} height={105} redraw />
```

within the "chartOption" variable I have added the following line:

```
onClick: this.handleBarClicked
```

This is a weird issue that i am facing - in chrome's dev console I can perform the action of:

```
this.chart.getElementAtEvent(evt)
```

and i get the expected value of the clicked bar column.
But within the code, this line throws the following error:

> main.jsx:116 Uncaught TypeError:
>   _this.chart.getElementAtEvent is not a function
>       at Chart. (main.jsx:116)
>       at Chart.handleEvent (Chart.js:8877)
>       at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:8820)
>       at listener (Chart.js:8758)
>       at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies. (Chart.js:6685)

Any ideas what could cause such an issue?

Comment: Try `this.chart.current.getElementAtEvent(evt)`

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue - the "this.chart" has an inner component called "this.chart.chartInstance"
this one contains the getElementAtEvent function!